# VHDL: including file type inside of a VHDL Record structure?

Tags: vhdl

In VHDL, is it possible to include a "file" type from textio package as an element of a record structure?  I want to have one fuction called init() to open a file, save the handler to the file in the record structure and then to have another function called next() that will read one record from the file descriptor in the record and load data into the record structure from the file on each call of next().

Example:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use std.textio.all;

entity testbench is
end entity;


architecture sim of sim_apb is

    type rec_t is record
        file  F    :text;     --Produces a syntax error
                              --  composite type not allowed
        state      :natural; 
    end record;

    signal rec: rec_t 
begin

end architecture;
```

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.3 Composite types, 5.3.1 "Composite types are used to define collections of values. These include both arrays of values ... and records of values (collections of values of potentially heterogeneous types).",  ... It is an error if a composite type contains elements of file types or protected types." It would seem likely you should be using a protected type instead of a record. This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) question.

Comment: files can be passed into procedures. The handle is updated for the next use of the file descriptor elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

When I have tried to remove *file* in your code, I got this error :

> ERROR: [VRFC 10-602] elements of file type are not allowed in composite types

So I think you can't use file type in record.

I didn't understand your needs very well but you may try to use String that is allowed in record.

Comment: That won't work. He needs access to the file descriptor as that keeps track of the file status, If it is opened or closed and how the reading has progressed.

Comment: I was able to work around the problem by keep File as a local variable to a process, and then passing the File descriptor into each procedure as a read only variable... strangely this work...  I pass in the File descriptor, then readline on the file inside of the procedure... works perfectly, but I had to cut and paste the init() procedure as an if-else branch  of the main process because there's no way to return the File descriptor to the calling process from a procedure.